# Select last record from my table

Tags: select, mysqli

I am new to SQL and PHP. I'm having a problem with selecting the last record from my table. I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 2521118 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

My table name is `2521118` and the fields are:

- id (set for auto-incrementing)
- timestamp
- meter_readings

Here is my error:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '2521118 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html), there are rules on what makes a valid identifier. This rule is what affects your case:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

So, as @ypercube says, you need to quote your table name, either with double quotes or backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM "2521118" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `2521118` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Double quotes didn't work but backquotes worked for me

Comment: @M.S.P Double quotes is the ANSI standard, but they're not supported out of the box in MySQL apparently... See [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) for more info.